# Relative Path for pom.xml with only a single pom.xml present

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml

Do we need to specify the relative path for pom.xml if we have only 1 pom.xml present in our directory ?

Comment: Can you post the folder structure of your project ? May be the pom itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a parent in your pom.xml which uses some kind of company pom which defines some global defaults etc. In those cases you have to omit the relative path in your pom.

Comment: Actuallt khmarbaise is correct.
There is a parent pom which uses a company pom
But when I run the project, it says 
Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find com.standardandpoors.idm:tools:pom:1.1.11-SNAPSHOT in http://gwt-recaptcha.googlecode.com/svn/repo was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of gwt-recaptcha has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 10 -> [Help 2]

Comment: @user1927060: I've rolled back your edit to this answer. You should put your image in the question, not the answer.

Comment: @CameronSkinner Sorry for that, I'm new to the site.

Comment: @user1927060: No problem. We all start somewhere :)

Comment: @user1927060 In the case of the given message you need to delete the path `$HOME/.m2/repository/com.standardandpoors` and rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

remove the parent in case you don't need it....